# Change Time & Data formatting in menu bar and Add another time to another location

Tags: panel, time, date

How could I change the format of the time and date in the Panel?
I don't mean change it from time and date Settings, but to my own format, like:

```
[day name , day- month name , month number -year / h(12):m:s / PM or AM name of city]
```

and add another time in the same format but to another location.

Comment: Recode the indicator, compile it, and run it on your system?  I don't think you can easily make these changes.

Comment: is there a way to hide system date and clock and build my own program and make it write in the menu bar ?